# In Unity, how do you program animations to update at a constant time per frame

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Does anyone know how to set up Unity so that animations made in its built in animation tool (pic below) update on a constant time scale. Basically, I want to make it so that no matter how much times passes in a frame, a constant float value will put it. I tried using animation.update() but this causes animation unctions to be called twice in a frame, which is rather un-ideal behavior.

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, what animation are you talking about? Unity build-in animation tool I suppose? There are many other animation you could be talking about.(ex-Live2D, Spine, Maya)

Comment: My apologies! The built in animation tool (pic above) is what I mean.